# Hacer find utilizando el resultado de otro find (que retorno multiples objetos)

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express

Lo que quiero hacer es con el resultado de un find (el cual me retorna varios objetos), volver a hacer un find en DB buscando todos los registros que tengan los id de los registros que obtuve en el anterior find (teniendo en cuenta que son multiples objetos y con diferentes id).

en el siguiente código me ayudare de los comentarios para explicarlo mejor:

```
function get(req,res){
    TG.find({_teacher:req.user.sub},(err,groups)=>{
        if(err){
            res.status(500).send({message:'Hubo un error al crear el grupo'});
        }else{
                if(groups){
                    **// aqui intento hacer un find con el id de los objetos
                      provenientes del anterior find, quiero saber como
                      hacerlo porque en este momento groups._id me devuelve
                      undefined ya que son varios objetos y no solo uno**
                    Groups.find({_id:groups._id},(err,groups)=>{
                        if(err){
                            res.status(500).send({message:'Error al buscar los grupos'});
                        }else{
                            if(groups){
                                res.status(200).send({groups});
                            }else{
                                res.status(404).send({message:'No tienes grupos'});
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    res.status(404).send({message:'No tienes grupos'});
                }
             }
    });
}
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Primero**: la primera consulta devuelve un cursor `groups`. La consulta anidada hace lo mismo. Eso se llama hacer `shadowing` y es una mala práctica. Si tu primera colección es de `teachers` usa ese nombre para el cursor.

**Segundo**, en vez de usar cursores, puedes usar Collection.find().toArray() para obtener los resultados como un arreglo y no tener que ir pidiendo `next` al cursor.

**Finalmente**: Los drivers más actualizados de MongoDB para nodejs retornan una promesa si no se le pasa un callback a `Collection.find` de modo que podrías hacer:

```
TG.find({_teacher:req.user.sub}).toArray().then(teachers)=>{

    if(!teachers.length) {
        res.status(404).send({message:'No tienes grupos'});
        return;
    }
    var groups_array = [],
    groups_promises = teachers.map(function(teacher) {
        return Groups.find({_id: teacher._id}).toArray().then((groups) => {
            groups_array.push(groups);
            return;
        });
    });

    return Promise.all(groups_promises).then(()=>{
        res.status(200).send(groups_array);
        return;
    });


}).catch((err)=> {
        res.status(500).send({message:err.message});
});
```

Esto devuelve un array de arrays. Si lo que quieres es un solo array con todos los grupos, puedes usar

```
groups_array = groups_array.concat(groups);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por las correcciones en las practicas, pero ahora me encuntro con un error al ejecutar el metodo toArray(), el error es el siguiente: TypeError: TG.find(...).toArray is not a function, tienes idea de porque ocurre? Muchas gracias

Comment: A lo mejor tendría que ser `TG.find().then((cursor)=> { return cursor.toArray()}).then((teachers) => {  ... })`

Comment: finalmente lo conseguí haciendo lo mismo solo que sin el método toArray()

Comment: enhorabuena como dicen los españoles